# facebook-api: what's Facebook Connect cross-domain receiver URL?

Tags: facebook, cross-domain

I'm trying to configure that my facebook application will be resizeable.

The docs at http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Resizable_IFrame

talk about facebook connect cross-domain receiver URL.

and in the JS code i need to enter the 'site relative url to xd_receiver.htm'.

what's that?

what code should be in that HTML file ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a file saved to your local web server. It allows Facebook to save a cookie that you have access to. Basically, it allows Facebook Connect to work.

Easiest thing to do is just place it in your web root (http://example.com/xd_receiver.htm)

This file should contain the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<head> 
    <title>Cross-Domain Receiver Page</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <script src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js?v2" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! placing the exact file in my web server and properly pointing FB.XdComm.Server.Init to that location resolves the issue!! i can properly resize my facebook app.

Comment: yay! congrats and enjoy making your facebook app :)